# How do I center a column with a max-width of 1280px inside a full width row with visual composer + css

Tags: css, wordpress, visual-composer

I'm building a site with wordpress, and i need to center a row with a max-width: 1280 that lives inside a full width row. This is the site link: http://creativa.co/selva/
and i'm trying to put the yellow row above the "6 Reasons why Colombia" row https://prnt.sc/meclxb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this on the div with the max-width?

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Also, in your case, the yellow block has some div before it, that is taking some space. You will need to hide it or remove it to make it work.